# What's the difference between Flux.concatMapIterable and Flux.flatMapIterable?

Tags: java, project-reactor

As subject, both `Flux.concatMapIterable` and `Flux.flatMapIterable` are not interleaved according to the marble diagram, unlike `Flux.concatMap` and `Flux.flatMap` which the `flatMap` is interleaved according to the marble diagram.

The `Flux.concatMapIterable` diagram is

[image: concatMapIterable]

And the `Flux.flatMapIterable` diagram is
[image: flatMapIterable]

Both resulting in sequence output.

Answer (score 3):

These two methods are effectively aliases of each other, both will consume each `Iterable` fully before processing the next one. This was just aliased for better discoverability in the API.

However, the marble diagram should be the same (concat one) in both methods, I'll fix that...

Comment: I guess the javadoc should say the same or saying that it is alias for the other. I was under impression that all flatMap is for interleaved and the concatMap is for sequential

Comment: I'll fix the javadoc too